# How to store runtime variables in a Maven project and access it from a different module during build

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module maven project ,where the modules call java classes.I want to store a variable and access it from other module.Can it be done using MavenProject? if yes how can I use it

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to sharing variables across pom.xml, You can set the variables in the  tag in the parent pom.xml and reference it from other modules.

something like

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</project.version>
    </properties>
```

and refer in the modules as ${project.version}

Answer (score 0):

When I had the same issue, I installed one module as a jar inside the other one.

Let's say I have a module A, and the Module B wants to access runtime variables in module B.

In module A I would put this line in the pom.xml

```
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

In module B I would import module A as a dependency

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.my.module.A</groupId>
     <artifactId>my-module-A</artifactId>
     <version>modueAversion</version>
 </dependency>
```

Then I would run a maven install in module B, which installs the module B in my repository.

After that update the dependencies in project A. In the maven dependencies section you should see an entry such as "moduleA.jar".

In this way, you can access all the runtime variables, classes, and methods of module A from module B.

I don't know if this is what you needed. I hope to have been of some help

Comment: yeah but would the jar contain runtime values?

Comment: Yes it will, you will also be able to run the code in the debug mode. Make sure you debug the .class file and not the .java.

If the import is successful, when you do CTR-R and type the name of your class, you should see two entrie: one .java (which is your original code) and one .class, which is the installed code.

When you change the code, do it in the .java, the make sure you run the maven install, in this way your code changes will be imported in your other module. This is very important.